# Google protocol buffers using MinGW in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, mingw

I am trying to use google protocol buffers from within Qt on Windows. Therefore I compiled the protobuf sources from github using msys from MingGW. The proto-compiler (protoc) seems to work fine, but unfortunately it does not work to use the generated .ph.h and .pb.cc files from within the Qt environment.

Added this to my .pro file:

```
LIBS += "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/libprotobuf-10.dll"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/include/"
```

but I still get "undefined reference to ..." at all the used methodes of the class when I try to compile it.

The code has to be correct, since it runs just fine on a linux machine using protoc and Qt. It has to be the way i include the .dll or I include a wrong one, since the headers seem to resolve fine.
Choose the dll to include according to this post: 
http://www.ptrackapp.com/apclassys-notes/building-google-protocol/

I am a bit lost here and would appreciate any held.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you developing MSYS? Why? None of what you allude to has any place as part of MSYS. Your own applications should ___never___ depend on any DLL in `C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin`, nor use any header in `C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/include`; those directories are reserved for the development of MSYS itself. Perhaps you intended to refer to the `C:/MinGW/include` and `C:/MinGW/bin` directories instead?

Comment: In order to use protocol buffers on windows I have to compile using MinGW or Cygwin (https://github.com/google/protobuf, see Windows section). But in order to be able to use the resulting ph.h and pb.cc files in my windows application i need the corresponding headers and libraries, which are obviously in the msys dir where i compiled it. Am i missing something, or how could I ever use them without the corresponding headers and libraries?

Comment: You are missing something. Compiling with MinGW, the headers and libraries you use ___must___ be in the `C:/MinGW/{include,lib,bin}` tree; you must ___not___ use components in the `C:/MinGW/msys/1.0` tree, for those are private to MSYS itself, and MinGW compilers do not use them.  Either you have installed your own self-built components incorrectly, or you are attempting to use components which are not intended for your use. In the latter case, you would need to port any missing components yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly figured it out, by using the following configuration prefix:

```
./configure --prefix=`cd /mingw; pwd -W`
```

Found the solution [here](http://w3facility.org/question/how-to-build-google-protocol-buffers-in-windows-for-mingw/)!

Comment: Good find. Try running `pwd -W` from a mingw shell (`msys.bat`) and see what you get, if you are curious.